# How can I get OnNewIntent to fire

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, xamarin.forms

I can't get OnNewIntent to fire. I've read dozens of articles on the issue and tried all combinations of code.

Regardless of whether I use LaunchMode.SingleTask or SingleTop it won't fire and always passes through the OnCreate method.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something? What do I need to add to get it to work?

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using static MyApp.ClipboardMgr;


namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    //[Activity(Label = "SplashActivity")]
    [Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", 
                MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]

    //Can't get this to work with LaunchMode.SingleTop or SingleTask. Always creates a new instance.
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionProcessText },
                Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
                DataMimeType = @"text/plain", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Label = "MyApp")]

    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            try
            {
                //taking these out for readability
                //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
                //TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
                //AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += AndroidEnvironment_UnhandledExceptionRaiser;

                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Create your application 
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));

                //don't want to do this here, better to do it in event
                if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionProcessText)
                {
                    //always comes here
                    HandleProcessTextIntent();

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                App.LogException(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// this is not firing!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intent"></param>
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);

            HandleProcessTextIntent();

        }

        void HandleProcessTextIntent()
        {
            string input = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraProcessText).Trim();

            if (input == string.Empty)
                return;

            ClipMgr.SetText(input);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to invoke onNewIntent() of SplashActivity ?

Comment: I want to invoke it on my app. SplashActivity is my MainLauncher so I thought it had to be invoked there. I've tried it on my so-called MainActivity and it won't fire there either.

Comment: So how you are invoking it ?

Comment: 1) I open my app 2) I switch to a browser and select text 3) the system context menu pops up with my MyApp menu item as specified in my Intent Label attribute 4) the Intent is triggered, but through the OnCreate method, and not my OnNewIntent method. No matter how many times I go back and forth to the browser, it will always create a new instance of my app and not pass through the OnNewIntent handler.

Comment: onNewIntent will only be called if your Activity is in the stack and you try to invoke the activity. In your case, I assume you are killing the SplashActivity,

Comment: Yes, I think the SplashActivity is getting killed, but even when I removed the SplashActivity and Launched from MainActivity it was the same issue. OnNewIntent still wouldn't fire. In fact I did another test today. I created a brand new Xamarin forms app (by default no splash), just added the LaunchMode, intent and its handler without touching anything else, and same problem. The handler simply won't fire.

Comment: Are you implementing deeplinking ?  Make sure your app is in the background then only the onNewOntent will be fired

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how deeplinking could help. Out of all I've read about this issue you are the first to mention that. It is also Play store related which seems unrelated to what I'm trying to achieve here. Please explain more. Yes, of course the app is in the background. Please see step 2) above.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't miss anything since when I test with my own intent to start your activity, it works well and the OnNewIntent() is called when SingleTask or SingleTop used, here's how I call the activity from another project(I did this in native Android):

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName("com.example.textHandlerDemo", "com.example.textHandlerDemo.TextHandlerActivity");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);
intent.setComponent(component);
startActivity(intent);
```

I did some research and find something that may explain why the OnNewIntent() never gets fired:

According to [the guidance of ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999#.h6377bc8j), it mentioned:

> You can use this as a hint to offer the ability to return altered text to the sending app, replacing the selected text. This works as your Activity was actually started with startActivityForResult()

So, when you click your app's label in the floating text selection toolbar, Android will start your activity registered with ActionProcessText with **startActivityForResult()**, and by using startActivityForResult(), your activity will be started as a sub-activity of current activity(implied from [Android doc of startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=zh-cn#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))), that is to say, rather than redirecting to your app which is already running, Android will put your activity into current app's stack.

This way, your target activity will still be called from OnCreate() since it's isolated from your running app.

Moreover, the floating text selection toolbar is used to provide a quick in-app experience for text operations like translation as mentioned in [this blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/in-app-translations-in-android.html), I didn't find any swich to enable/disable redirect to app, you may need to handle the intent in both OnCreate() and OnNewIntent() if you're using LaunchMode.SingleTask or SingleTop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but didn't quite understand a few points. 1) how did you get the event to fire, but then say why it might not fire? Did it fire or not?  Because it has never fired for me. 2) I don't need to replace selected text. How can I call this without this functionality and thus avoid startActivityForResult() which you say is causing my problem.

Comment: @jhowe sorry for miss the point, I made a call from another project with startActivity() and the OnNewIntent is fired, but when I long click in Chrome text and select my app in the floating text selection toolbar, it's start as a sub-activity and the OnCreate is called, updated answer with the startActivity call from another project.